# Android GCM - WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService crash due to IllegalStateException 8.0

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo, legacy-app

We just migrated app's target api to Android API 27 (8.1) and it keeps on crashing when notification arrives specially when the app is in the background.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver <package>.service.GCMBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=<package> cmp=<package>/.service.GCMIntentService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{b248a9d u0a85 RCVR bg:+1m4s53ms idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=<package> cmp=<package>/.service.GCMIntentService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{b248a9d u0a85 RCVR bg:+1m4s53ms idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1521)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1477)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:650)
    at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService(WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:99)
    at <package>.service.GCMBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GCMBroadcastReceiver.java:32)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3187)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Switch to FCM.. Follow the Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: FCM is good but migration might takes time, our app is already in the Playstore.

Comment: I already find answer.

Comment: Note that GCM is deprecated. You definitely should migrate to FCM.

Comment: Exactly. For now we need work around. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I fix the issue:

**Why this issue happens?**

> Due to the new [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services) of Android 8 and you should
>   not start services background.

**How I fixed it**

Migrate your `GCMIntetService` to `JobIntentService` instead of `IntentService`.

Please follow this steps:
1) Add the BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission to your service:

```
<service android:name=".service.GCMIntentService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
```

2) In your `GCMIntentService`, instead extending the `IntentService`, use `android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService` and override onHandleWork
then remove the `override` in you `onHandleIntent`.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    // Service unique ID
    static final int SERVICE_JOB_ID = 50;

    // Enqueuing work in to this service.
    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, GCMIntentService.class, SERVICE_JOB_ID, work);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        onHandleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //Handling of notification goes here
    }
}
```

Then finally, in your `GCMBroadcastReceiver`, enqueue your `GCMIntentService`.

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        // startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

        //setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

        GCMIntentService.enqueueWork(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    }
}
```

This implementation work for me after we update our target sdk to 27 and I hope it works for you.